# How can I spawn multiple processes concurrently from Supervisor?

Tags: elixir

I have been trying to start multiple processes of the same module from my Supervisor module by changing the arguments and the id. However, I see that the children processes are being spawned in a sequential manner.

When using spawn or spawn link it works fine but then I am not calling the worker method and the processes won't be supervised. 
Is there any other method in the Supervisor module which will allow doing this concurrently?

Comment: No. Elixir (and Erlang) code is run sequentially. If a supervisor were to start its children concurrently, it would need to start additional processes just to start your workers. Process on the BEAM are cheap, but I'm sure starting your `GenServer` (or whatever behaviour) is still faster then starting process just to start other processes. There is also the different restart strategies you have to think about. For example, the `rest_for_one` strategy is used for when your processes need to be started (and restarted) in a specific order. So concurrency would actually be detremental in that case

Comment: While going through the documentations I found out that all the behaviour modules are an abstraction of bare processes. Now the bare processes can be spawned parallelly using `spawn` but `start_link` method in `GenServer` is sequential. I was wondering why are there no methods to start the processes in parallel.

Comment: "**Is there** any other method in the Supervisor module which will allow doing this concurrently?" - Your question was asking if you could. Not why you can't. The answer to why you can't is because supervisors call `start_link` so that it has a link to the process so it knows when it crashes and will restart accordingly. If it had no link to the process, it would not be supervising it.

Answer (score 0):

> When using [`Kernel.spawn/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html?#spawn/3) or [`Kernel.spawn_link/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html?#spawn_link/3) it works fine but then I am not calling the `worker` method and the processes won't be supervised.

There are many issues here. In the first place, we don’t have methods in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), we have functions. [`Supervisor.Spec.worker/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Supervisor.Spec.html?#worker/3) is **deprecated** and should not be used. One should use [child specifications](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Supervisor.html#module-child-specification) instead.

And, of course, you can supervise started processes with a help of [`Process.monitor/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Process.html?#monitor/1) (here is an example of how core [`DynamicSypervisor`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/DynamicSupervisor.html?) [does that](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/31aea21ccb5b534bdf75f5d71d2566d5418e4f58/lib/elixir/lib/dynamic_supervisor.ex#L812-L824),) but this is *not* what you actually want to do.

Heavy initialization should be put into [`GenServer.handle_continue/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/GenServer.html?#c:handle_continue/2) callback of your workers. That way it will be executed in the process and your initialization would return immediately; actually it would be somewhat “concurrent” loading, but the processes would still be sequentially ordered, making it easier to tackle with.

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks